# How to automatically include a number of images in the SWF file?

Tags: actionscript-3

i'm trying to include a number of images in my SWF file not by loading them but by embedding them in the SWF itself. I found the following instruction to do that:

`[Embed(source="../graphics/images/ss0.png")]
        private var SS0:Class;`

Basically, i want to embed a different number of images each time. Is there a way to do that automatically (let's say inside a for loop) or do i have to type manually this instruction for each image i want to include?

Comment: Hey, do you really need to include them that way ? There's a few workarounds but they're all quite dirty ...

Comment: yes unfortunately i have to embed the graphic files in the SWF file to reduce the download rate from the server. Please feel free to enlighten me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could store all your PNG files in a single ZIP file, then use the [FZip](http://codeazur.com.br/lab/fzip/) class to extract them. See [the example of this on their site](http://codeazur.com.br/lab/fzip/demo/).

Comment: thanks for pointing this class, but is not what i need because i will have to deliver a ZIP file beside the SWF.

Comment: Why do you need everything to be in a single SWF file? Just downloading one extra file from your server is not going to be very much overhead. Eg every time you visit a webpage it downloads many many things (images, CSS, javascript, etc etc)